# validate particular remarks when unchecked respective checkbox

Tags: angular

I want to validate particular remarks ie not empty if respective checkbox unchecked. When submit form and unchecked checkbox and remark is empty.

I am trying the following form

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6jewe

Answer (score 0):

```
On form submit, write the condition *ngIf="f.submitted && f.valid". Look at the code below:
<div>
      <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.valid, names)" novalidate>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Initial</th>
          <th>Remark</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let name of names">
          <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="name.checked" [checked]="true" [name]="name.id + '_checkbox'"></td>
          <td>{{name.id}}</td>
          <td>{{name.name}}</td>
          <td>{{name.Initial}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name.remark" required [disabled]="name.checked"  [name]="name.id+ '_remark'"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <div *ngIf="f.submitted && f.invalid" class="invalid-feedback" style="color:red;">
                            <div >Please fill the details</div>
                        </div></tr>
      </table>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div>
          <div>Form details:-</div>
          <pre *ngIf="f.submitted && f.valid">submitted value: <br>{{names | json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Swati, I want to validate the particular remark which is empty